# url rewriting "double path for same file"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an issue with my htaccess file but I dont understand where the mistake comes from:

Ex:

I have the following file in my folder

- contact.php

I did a basic rewrite like that

```
 RewriteRule    ^about/$    contact.php [L]
```

so now my contact page is accessible from `http://localhost/project/about/`

the problem is that page is also accessible from

- `http://localhost/project/contact/`

Why is this happening?
How can I disallow that?

Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to enabling of option `MultiViews`. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

To disallow this you can add this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```